# Check, with jquery, if a specific dropdown option is selected, and if it is, enable/show a hidden/disabled dropdown box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I'm loading data from a database table directly into a form's dropdown box. I'm trying to check on page load if a specific value is set into this box and if it is I want to enable another dropdown box which is disabled and hidden by default.

I'm using Chronoforms v5 for the form creation (joomla) and I have setup events which enable & show the 2nd dropdown box if a specific value is chosen in the 1st dropdown box, and reversely if no value is chosen in the 1st dropdown, or a value different than the one I want, I disable & hide the 2nd dropdown box. But these events happen only after the user is actively changing the values in the 1st dropdown box. I need the events to happen on page loading as well.

Chronoform's javascript is

```
function chronoforms_fields_events(){

    $(':input[name="custom"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'United_States'){
            $(':input[name="state"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $(':input[name="custom"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'United_States'){

            if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').length > 0){
                $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').show();
                }else if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').length > 0){
                $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').show();
            }

        }
    });

    $(':input[name="custom"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() != 'United_States'){

            if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').length > 0){
                $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').hide();
                }else if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').length > 0){
                $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').hide();
            }

        }
    });

    $(':input[name="custom"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() != 'United_States'){
            $(':input[name="state"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    $(':input[name="custom"]').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(':input[name="state"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
}
chronoforms_fields_events();
```

And I'm currently adding this javascript  before the HTML (Render form) but it doesn't work

```
 function validatecountry(){
 if ($("#custom").prop("selectedIndex", 'United_States')){
          $(':input[name="state"]').prop('disabled', false);
    if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').length > 0){
                     $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-subinput-container').show();
                }else if($(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').length > 0){
                $(':input[name="state"]').closest('.gcore-form-row').show();
            }

 }
 }
 validatecountry();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you call this function before the form renders, `$("#custom")`, `$('input[name="state"]')`, etc will not return anything & hence your code would not work. Add the call into a ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  validatecountry();
}
```

To the first part of your question, you can manually trigger a change on the input fields after DOM is ready which would call the change routine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="custom"]').trigger("change");
}
```

Comment: actually I am doing that with jQuery(document).ready(function($) but stackoverflow wouldn't let me add it the above code (I'm not expereinced with the system here) so I left it out

Comment: What does this line actually do: `if ($("#custom").prop("selectedIndex", 'United_States')){`

Comment: should perhaps be `if($("#custom").val()=="United_States") {` ?

Comment: ssp thank you, this put me on the right track. The problem was two-fold. First I made the change you suggested and then I loaded the custom javascript AFTER the HTML (render form) in chronoforms. Problem solved

Comment: (y) leave a trace / add an answer so that the ones who stumble upon this link later would be helped